# Shaders linked but not working for some people

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, shader

I've written OpenGL programs in C++ and Python and all the computer that get this message

`vertex shader(s) linked fragment shader(s) linked`

show a blank screen. All others that can see the graphics have no messages what so ever from glGetProgramInfoLog()
My laptop shows that message and can't see anything. A specific example. I have Opengl 3.1 a friend of mine has 3.2 he can't see anything I always can. He gets that message. This happens on my C++ program too. Is it required to validate the program first? 3 of 7 people can't see anything and they all get that message. The ones that can see it don't get a single message from the shader.

Heres everything on my shaders.

```
def init_shaders(self):
    vert_shader=glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    frag_shader=glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    vert_text="""
    varying vec2 texcoord;
    attribute vec3 inputvertex;
    uniform float ifintex;
    attribute vec2 input_texcoord;
    void main() {
        texcoord = (gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy*ifintex)+input_texcoord.xy;
        vec4 position = vec4(inputvertex,1.0);
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
    }
    """

    frag_text="""
    uniform sampler2D texture_map;
    uniform vec4 add_color;

    varying vec2 texcoord;

    void main(){

        gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture_map, texcoord.xy)+add_color;

    }
    """

    glShaderSource(vert_shader,vert_text)
    glShaderSource(frag_shader,frag_text)

    glCompileShader(vert_shader)
    glCompileShader(frag_shader)

    self.Shader=glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(self.Shader,vert_shader)
    glAttachShader(self.Shader,frag_shader)
    glLinkProgram(self.Shader)
    error=glGetProgramInfoLog(self.Shader)
    if error!="":
        print error
    else:
        print "Shaders Compiled"

    glUseProgram(self.Shader)
```

Anything wrong? I thought it was just a notification but its all a way too suspicious pattern.

Comment: Shaders get errors too. You have to look at the shader infolog as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying that you're using GLSL 1.20 by adding this to the top of your shaders:

```
#version 120
```

Anything else is probably a minor difference between implementations. I know that on the Intel implementation calling `texture2D` when no texture is bound returns `(0, 0, 0, 1)` while NVIDIA and ATI implementations return `(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Other than that your shaders look fine, try messing around with them on your friends' machines to see where the issue is.

Also ask your friends what GPU they have to see which implementations are displaying errors.

Oh, and you want to be checking the value of `GL_LINK_STATUS` with `glGetProgramiv` instead of seeing if the log is empty. Some implementations write to the log on success as well as on failure. `GL_LINK_STATUS` is always `0` on success.

Comment: Thanks very much I didn't see the connection. Their all ati's. :( Only works on nvidia! I'll see what i can do.

Comment: One bug-causing difference between NVIDIA and ATI implementations that I've encountered is that NVIDIA will automatically bind attribute locations to the order they appear in your shader, while ATI changes that order (the spec never guarantees that order). Add the following two lines just before linking the program:

`glBindAttribLocation(self.Shader, 0, "inputvertex")`
`glBindAttribLocation(self.Shader, 1, "input_texcoord")`

Comment: It looks like it worked but the render is sooo slow. His card is faster than mine XD.

Answer (score 1):

What matters even more than OpenGL version is the Driver vendor. Different drivers have distinct output. So it is very likely that your program is not compatible with some drivers (ATI, NVidia, or Intel). You should find out what video cards your program works on and which ones it fails on.

As far as I can tell your shaders look fine. Also you never get any errors or warnings from the driver, other than the info message. So the most likely suspect is mip-map texture initialization, that is known to be buggy on ATI: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Automatic_mipmap_generation.

You have not presented the full program code. So another possibility is you are binding to a constant attribute location. Video card drivers can produce distinct attribute location mapping, even between runs on the same system.

TLDR: Your shader is fine, the problem is elsewhere. The bug is most likely driver vendor dependent (ATI, NVidia, or Intel).

Comment: No mipmaps unfortunately. I am requesting locations so that not a problem. I checked to see if immediate mode wasn't working but buffers don't work either.